# Rename txt files in multiple subfolders

Tags: excel, vba

So I have a folder called "Test" and with in the folder there are subfolders with different names (in column A) and there is a txt files in each subfolder called "indexpre".

I need to rename the file to what I have in column C in excel.

I have tried using other code that I have seen online but I get the same error.

```
Sub ReNameFiles()

Dim myPath As String
Dim fullPath As String
myPath = "C:\Users\cooketd\Desktop\Test"

r = 1

For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
    fullPath = myPath & "\" & cell & "\"

    Name fullPath & "indexpre.txt" As fullPath & Cells(r, 3).Value & ".txt"
   r = r + 1

Next cell

End Sub
```

When I run the code I get an error on this line

```
Name fullPath & "indexpre.txt" As fullPath & Cells(r, 3).Value & ".txt"
```

to say Run-time error '53': File not found.

I have checked the source file and the file path is correct and the file "indexpre.txt" is present.

I have also removed the .txt from that line of code and it made no difference to the outcome.

I would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: use debug.print  fullPath & "indexpre.txt"  :debug.print  fullPath & Cells(r, 3).Value & ".txt"

Comment: instead of `Cells(r, 3)` you might want to refer to the actual cell, that will be more consistent: `cell.Offset(0,2).value`!

Comment: Thanks Ronan.  It would seem that it is not reading the cell in A1. C:\Users\cooketd\Desktop\Test\\indexpre.txt
C:\Users\cooketd\Desktop\Test\\.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aData As Variant
    Dim sInitialPath As String
    Dim sFullPath As String
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim sFileToRename As String
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    aData = ws.Range("A1:C" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value

    sInitialPath = Environ("UserProfile") & "\Desktop\Test"
    If Right(sInitialPath, 1) <> "\" Then sInitialPath = sInitialPath & "\"

    sFileToRename = "indexpre.txt"

    For i = LBound(aData, 1) To UBound(aData, 1)
        sFullPath = sInitialPath & aData(i, 1)
        If Right(sFullPath, 1) <> "\" Then sFullPath = sFullPath & "\"
        sFileName = Dir(sFullPath & sFileToRename)
        If Len(sFileName) > 0 Then Name sFullPath & sFileName As sFullPath & aData(i, 3) & ".txt"
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks tigeravatar, it all works until 

If Len(sFileName) > 0 Then Name sFullPath & sFileName As sFullPath & aData(i, 3) & ".txt"


It does If Len(sFileName) > 0 and then skips Then Name sFullPath & sFileName As sFullPath & aData(i, 3) & ".txt"

Comment: I have figured that I needed to remove  Dir and the () and then it sets sFileName which then moves the code on to "Then name..." but then it fails saying "File not found"

Comment: I have now figured it out, I needed to remove the first sFullPath from the last line.  Works a treat now.

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use variables and see if the file really exist , u can print the names from ThisName and see if the value is really what you want

```
Dim thisName as string
dim toThisName as string 

thisName =  fullPath & "indexpre.txt" 
toThisName =  fullPath & Cells(r, 3).Value & ".txt"

if vba.dir(thisName) = "" then 
   'file not found
    stop
end if 

Name thisName  As toThisName
```

Comment: Thanks Ronan, with this code I'm getting 1004 application-defined or object-defined error.  As you can tell im trying to learn VBA, but seems to be at a snails pace at the moment

Comment: Try change Cells(r, 3) for Cells(cell.row, 3)

Comment: Now I'm getting Run time error 424: Object required

Comment: Cell.offset(0,2).value , this will get the column C value

Comment: It would seem that it is missing the subfolder that is A1. 
 Currently shows as this C:\Users\cooketd\Desktop\Test\\indexpre.txt but should be this C:\Users\cooketd\Desktop\Test\Value of A1 here\indexpre.txt

Comment: But debug.print cell.Row & " " & cell.Column , Before Line of name and see the values , Try to debug.print cell.value too

Comment: i would have thought that this would have picked up the cell range to look at 

For Each cell In Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
    fullPath = myPath & "\" & cell & "\"

Comment: U need to declare dim Cell as range

Comment: range() returns the Range from active Sheet , Change that for Sheets("YourSheetName").Range()

Comment: Debug.Print cell.Value gives me the correct subfolder name that i need.

Comment: change to fullPath = myPath & "\" & cell.value & "\"